# How to run a AWS CLI command using crontab for every minute

Tags: shell, amazon-web-services, cron, amazon-rds

I have AWS CLI Command to create db snapshot, I want to create db snapshot with current time stamp.
I could not able to run the command using cron tab.

**To create an Amazon RDS DB instance** use below command

```
aws rds create-db-instance --db-instance-identifier testrds --allocated-storage 5 --db-instance-class db.m1.small --engine mysql --availability-zone us-east-1d --master-username rajuuser --master-user-password mrajuuser --port 7007 --no-multi-az --no-auto-minor-version-upgrade
```

**To create db snapshot** use below command

```
aws rds create-db-snapshot --db-instance-identifier testrds --db-snapshot-identifier testrds
```

**shell script** what I am following

```
#!/bin/sh
#echo "Hello world"

now=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S")
cd /home/ubuntu
cmd="$(aws rds create-db-snapshot --db-instance-identifier testrds --db-snapshot-identifier testrds:"$(now)")"

echo $cmd
```

Comment: This sounds like a bad idea.  What is your use case for creating a snapshot every minute? This is likely to get cost prohibitive very quickly, not to mention that it'll likely take _longer_ than 60 seconds to create your snapshot.  If you're wanting this for 'backup' purposes, consider just using the built in RDS backup's combined with 'point-in-time' recovery (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_PIT.html)

Comment: Peterson, My intention is to get solution from people, and to run this script. I just mentioned time as in minutes, actually I need it as daily once. We know that AWS RDS will only give 35 days backup, So I want to take a db snapshot manually on daily once. For this do you know anything?

Comment: What is the problem? `could not able to run the command ` means nothing. Try giving full path to `aws`. What do you achieve by `cd /home/ubuntu`?

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error, and I found that providing the full path to the aws cli solved the issue (for me was on a different path that the one in hjpotter answer).

```
#!/bin/sh
HOME="/home/ubuntu"
AWS_CONFIG_FILE="/home/ubuntu/.aws/config"
d=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M")
/home/ubuntu/.local/bin/aws rds create-db-snapshot --db-instance-identifier myid --db-snapshot-identifier prod-scheduled-$d
```

As AWS creates RDS snapshots only once per day, my requirements were to create several snapshots each day, at a fixed schedule, fired from a cronjob (e.g. at 6am, 10am, 2pm, 6pm, 10pm).

So, to keep "reasonable" costs, I also added a step to delete all "cron" snapshots taken yesterday:

```
y=$(date -d "1 day ago" +"%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M")
aws rds delete-db-snapshot --db-snapshot-identifier prod-scheduled-$y
```

This way I can keep one snapshot per day for historical purposes, and several snapshots from the last 24hs in case I need to shorter gaps.

Although this was not part of the question, it was commented by Luke Petersen as cost-prohibitive, and maybe someone else is having the same requirements (as I did).

One last thing: a similar (and AFAIK, a cleaner) solution can be achieved by using [Restore to a point in time](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_PIT.html) feature, which uses the daily snapshots and the transaction log to restore a db-instance to a custom specific date and time (within the backup retention period).

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar cron task setup for backing up certain instances in EC2. Here is how I set it up:

```
$ crontab -l
0 14 * * * /usr/bin/zsh /home/hjpotter92/snapshot.zsh
```

and the contents of `snapshot.zsh`:

```
#!/usr/bin/zsh

HOME="/home/hjpotter92"
AWS_HOME="$HOME/.aws"
PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:$PATH"
DATE=`date +%c`

aws ec2 create-snapshot --volume-id XXXXXXXX \
    --description "${DATE}" \
    --profile hjpotter92 \
    --region "us-west-2" >> /home/hjpotter92/cron.out 2>&1
```

Note that while my script above is executable (`x` permission bit set), I still provide the shell name to it.

The problem is, you have string/variable interpolation issues with the command.

Also, `/bin/sh` does not have a lot of features which other shells provide. Change the head section of script to use bash(?).

```
#!/bin/bash
now=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S")
cd /home/ubuntu
aws rds create-db-snapshot --db-instance-identifier testrds --db-snapshot-identifier "testrds:${now}" >> some-log.txt
```

Comment: Potter, I will implement this solution for RDS and let you know, Thanks.